# Is There a Way to Print Preferably to a Connected Printer?

Tags: usb, printing, configuration, settings

I use my laptop in two offices, each one with its printer connected via USB. Unfortunately I keep sending documents to print to the wrong printer. 
I would like my documents to be send automatically to the attached printer. Does someone know how?

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution: go to "Printers" and delete the printer not connected, then re-install when needed.

Comment: A better answer still needed.

Comment: did you solve this??

Comment: No. I still use the solution I mention (delete not used printers). I just made a script to do it automatically.

Comment: Isn't there some sort of default printer thingy, or am I just remembering wrong?

Comment: There is the option "-d" with the command "lpadmin" but I could not make it work.